# How to avoid rename refactoring bug in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mercurial, refactoring

I have a strange rename bug in my Eclipse Indigo SP2 workspace in a m2e 1.0 project (maven integration for eclipse) with a MercurialEclipse 2.0 shared project. I refactor a java class by renaming it from e.g. FormPaneFactory to XYZFormPaneFactory. The references to the java class are updated correctly, also the compilation unit is renamed correctly, but the source of the class file itself gets scrambled in a difficult to explain way. I made a diff screenshot:

[image]

I got not reproduce this with a smaller/more reduced example. However it is reproducible with all examples larger as this. Do you know this bug? Should it be filed? If yes, where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the linked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6593625/1184842)

The problem are the flags for mercurial in the top:

```
/*
 * Created on 24.04.2014
 *
 * Copyright (c) jan, 2014
 *
 * $Author$
 * $Revision$
 * $Date$
 */
```

If they are removed, the bug disappears.

Comment: Is there any eclipse setting that influences this?

Comment: Problem is the keyword extension of mercurial http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension

Comment: This bug seems related or the reason, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339866